# How to add BLAS_LIB in my Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, blas

I am using BLAS_LIB in my project to perform matrix multiplication. This is my CMakelist.txt. It was missing the path to BLAS_LIB and BLAS_INCLUDE file. I think it is the reason for the below error. If is the correct reason, please help me to fix it?

This is my CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testconv)
if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()
add_executable(testconv main.cpp)

install(TARGETS testconv RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

This is the error

```
/home/projects/TestConv/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
```

This is my cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cblas.h>
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    //Random numbers
    std::mt19937_64 rnd;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> doubleDist(0, 1);

    //Create Arrays that represent the matrices A,B,C
    const int n = 20;
    double*  A = new double[n*n];
    double*  B = new double[n*n];
    double*  C = new double[n*n];

    //Fill A and B with random numbers
    for(uint i =0; i <n; i++){
        for(uint j=0; j<n; j++){
            A[i*n+j] = doubleDist(rnd);
            B[i*n+j] = doubleDist(rnd);
        }
    }

    //Calculate A*B=C
    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n, n, n, 1.0, A, n, B, n, 0.0, C, n);

    //Clean up
    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;
    delete[] C;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which CMake version? Try `cmake --version`.

Comment: Hi, it is `cmake version 3.5.2`

Comment: `It was missing the path to BLAS_LIB and BLAS_INCLUDE file. I think it is reason for bellow error. If is correct reason, please help me to fix it?` - Yes, absence of linking is the reason of `undefined reference` error. Is it new for you? If your problem is to find BLAS library, [find_package(BLAS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBLAS.html) should help, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're completely forgetting to include the BLAS library.
For your CMake version CMake includes a `FindBLAS.cmake` file, which will not work in your case. 
You will need `FindCBLAS.cmake` that correctly will find the C interface to BLAS as done in other open source projects.
You can grab for example the following https://github.com/Eyescale/CMake/blob/master/FindCBLAS.cmake.
First of all you will need to create a directory called `cmake` in your project root directory (not in the build directory!!!), then copy that file I just mentioned (`FindCBLAS.cmake`).
You will need to modify your `CMakeLists.txt` in the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(testconv)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(CBLAS REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR})
if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()
add_executable(testconv main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testconv ${CBLAS_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS testconv RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Try that. It can be improved, but should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new user for BLAS. I added it and I got the error `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):   Cannot specify link libraries for target "/usr/lib/libf77blas.so" which is   not built by this project.`, event I got `-- A library with BLAS API found.
`

Comment: basically write `target_link_libraries(testconv ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: Thank. It shown that Configuring done but making an error as `/home/projects/TestConv/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to cblas_dgemm'`

Comment: in your code try: `extern "C"
{
   #include <cblas.h>
}`  or   
`#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
   #include <cblas.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif`

Comment: If it works, I will include in my answer too and update.

Comment: I am using g++ complie. I added it in main.cpp but it still has the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133970/discussion-between-fedepad-and-user8264).